# Google news sitemap to many URLs

Tags: google, sitemap

I created a Google news sitemap a while ago then about 6 months ago limited it to about 15 news items. The trouble is it seems Google has indexed over a 1000 items and is complaining the sitemap has to many URLs when if you go to the sitemap it doesn't, just 15, any ideas? Have resubmitted the sitemap and says it was last processed yesterday.

Comment: try to rename it and resubmit again. Test it before submit it, you can do this directly from webmaster tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think it was a Cache thing, checked it the next day and webmaster tools had updated correctly.